# Error while implementing word wise count on unstructured data in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, max, apache-pig

I am running this hive query in order to get word wise count on an unstructured data.

```
select a, count(*) from (select(EXPLODE(SPLIT(regexp_replace(upper(word,'[-!@#$%&*]',''))) AND EXPLODE(SPLIT(regexp_replace(UPPER(word,'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]','')))) as A from file)q group by a;
```

BUT Im getting below as an error. Not able to figure out the solution to it.

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:46 Wrong arguments
>   '''': No matching method for class
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpReplace with (string). Possible
>   choices: *FUNC*(string, string, string)

Comment: SQL 1 liners are a bad idea. Start with formatting your query properly.

Answer (score 0):

regexp_replace is for replacing it have 3 arguments

`(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text s, org.apache.hadoop.io.Text regex, org.apache.hadoop.io.Text replacement)`

you should rather use regexp_extract

```
evaluate(String s, String regex)
```

Comment: But I'm using three arguments : EXPLODE(SPLIT(regexp_replace(UPPER(word,'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]','')))) --> (string to be processed(word), string to be replaced('[^A-Za-z0-9 ]'), replacment ('')

Comment: 3 arguments you are giving for UPPER , UPPER(word,'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]','')

Comment: Okay, even if I dont give Upper and give directly regexp_replace, I get the same error. Tried that, dint resolve the issues. :(

Comment: `select a, count(*) from (select(EXPLODE(SPLIT(regexp_replace(word,'[-!@#$%&*]','')) AND EXPLODE(SPLIT(regexp_replace(word,'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]',''))) as A from file)q group by a`